# Do not add to list if it is null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a list from anonymous function. I want the list to be created if request model properties are not null. Currently, it is adding null to the list

**Here's what I have so far**:

```cs
public void method (RequestModel request)
{
    var create = new DtoModel
    {
        docs = new List<docsModel>
        {
            request.FirstDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.FirstDoc) : null,
            request.SecondDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.SecondDoc) : null,
            request.ThirdDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.ThirdDoc) : null,
        }
    };
}
```

Currently, it is creating a list of count 3 even if any of the docs are null. I would list to be only created if docs are not null and the list should only contain docs that are not null. There should not be any null values. Request model can have x number of docs.

I know I can use Linq to remove nulls afterwards but I am looking for a solution where it does not create null elements in list.

Comment: There are some contradictions in your requirements. Do you want either a) the list to not be created at all if even one of the docs are null or b) the list to be created but to discard any docs which are null? In your description you have mentioned both possibilities. But in either case you will need to check the value of each document **before** creating a list entry. Right now you are creating an entry first and then deciding if it should be null or not.

Comment: You should implement your list by implement IList<docsModel>.

Answer (score 16):

Basically you can't do that with a collection initializer - a collection initializer *always* adds the same number of elements as there are entries in the comma-separated list. (I suppose you could have a collection whose `Add` method ignores null values, but `Add` will definitely be called the same number of times.)

Instead, just use `if` statements:

```
if (request.FirstDoc != null)
{
    create.docs.Add(runFunction(request.FirstDoc));
}
// etc
```

You could always use a local method to simplify that:

```
public void method (RequestModel request)
{
     var create = new DtoModel { docs = new List<docsModel>() };
     MaybeAdd(request.FirstDoc);
     MaybeAdd(request.SecondDoc);
     MaybeAdd(request.ThirdDoc);

     void MaybeAdd(docsModel doc)
     {
         if (doc != null)
         {
             create.docs.Add(runFunction(doc));
         }
     }
}
```

I'd originally missed the part about the list itself not being initialized if everything is null. For that, you'd need to change it to check for initialization each time you want to add to it as well:

```
public void method (RequestModel request)
{
     var create = new DtoModel();
     MaybeAdd(request.FirstDoc);
     MaybeAdd(request.SecondDoc);
     MaybeAdd(request.ThirdDoc);

     void MaybeAdd(docsModel doc)
     {
         if (doc != null)
         {
             if (create.docs == null)
             {
                 create.docs = new List<docsModel>();
             }
             create.docs.Add(runFunction(doc));
         }
     }
}
```

As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend that you start following normal .NET naming conventions, with PascalCase for both types and properties (`DocsModel`, `Method`, `RunFunction`, `Docs`).

Comment: Plus I want to recommend (humbly) to OP that s/he checks how ternary operator works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: @burkay: I see no indication that they *don't* know what the conditional operator does. I don't think that's the part that's confusing them.

Answer (score 3):

### Use Linq

You can accomplish what you want with a little LINQ.

```
var create = new DtoModel
{
    docs = (new [] 
    { 
        request.FirstDoc, 
        request.SecondDoc, 
        request.ThirdDoc
    })
    .Where( d => d != null)
    .Select( d => runFunction(d))
    .ToList()
};
```

### Longer but easier to read

That's a little hard to read, so I suggest breaking it down a little.

Create a helper method to unroll the requests into an array:

```
static public T[] CreateArray<T>(params T[] input)
{
    return input;
}
```

And then write it this way:

```
var requests = CreateArray
(
    request.FirstDoc, 
    request.SecondDoc, 
    request.ThirdDoc
);

var processedRequests = requests
    .Where( r => r != null)
    .Select( r => runFunction(r));

var create = new DtoModel
{
    docs = processedRequests.ToList()
};
```

Or if you like using the ternary operator, as in your example, you could do it like this:

```
public void method (RequestModel request)
{
    var create = new DtoModel
    {
        docs= CreateArray
        (
            request.FirstDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.FirstDoc) :null,
            request.SecondDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.SecondDoc) : null,
            request.ThirdDoc!= null ? runFunction(request.ThirdDoc) : null,
        }
        .Where( d => d != null)
        .ToList()
     };
}
```

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocFE6r) for the full example on DotNetFiddle.

Comment: OP stated not to use linq. And I agree with him. To construct a list with nulls and then construct another one with nulls filtered away does make less sense than construct it the right way from the beginning.

Comment: Read carefully. I believe he didn't want to use linq to "remove nulls afterward," i.e. wanted the magic to happen within the collection initializer. I think my code does exactly that.

Comment: In your last example you create an array then filter nulls (_Where(...)_) then create a _List_ out of it. That is what the code does

Comment: What list? I don't see any list. I see an `IEnumerable`. The list is created once, with `ToList()`, with the correct number of elements... all inside the collection initializer.